# UNION ALL query causes type conversion error but UNION doesn't

Tags: sql, ms-access

When I run the following query:

```
INSERT INTO outRawTbl
SELECT *
FROM (select * from [out|noRFI_BS_noRT]
union all
select * from [out|noRFI_BS_RT])  AS [%$##@_Alias];
```

I get this error:

```
Microsoft Access set 3854 field(s) to Null due to a type conversion failure
```

When I run the query as:

```
INSERT INTO outRawTbl
SELECT *
FROM (select * from [out|noRFI_BS_noRT]
union
select * from [out|noRFI_BS_RT])  AS [%$##@_Alias];
```

then I don't get this type conversion error, and all the data inserts successfully.  I need to use `UNION ALL` because some of the fields in the queries are Memo fields and they'll be truncated to 255 chars if I use `UNION`.

I guess I can start trying to insert fields one at a time from the queries, but there are around 50 fields in each query and that will take a lot of time.  Is there a quick way to find out which field is causing the problem with `UNION ALL`?

EDIT:
Solved and uncovered another problem.  I took Gordon's idea of running the queries as separate `INSERT` operations instead of using  `UNION ALL`.  I then iterated through each field in the query, doing a separate insert to find the field that was causing the conversion error, using this code:

```
Sub findProblemField()

Dim qdf As QueryDef
Dim sql As String
Dim fld As Field   

For Each qdf In CurrentDb.QueryDefs
    If InStr(qdf.Name, "out|") Then
        For Each fld In qdf.Fields
            sql = "insert into outrawtbl select top 1 " & _
                    "[" & qdf.Name & "].[" & fld.Name & "] from [" & qdf.Name & "]"
            CurrentDb.Execute sql, dbFailOnError
        Next
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

This led me to discover that one of the fields that is a string in the `SELECT` query is a Date/Time in the destination field, and a blank string value is what's throwing the error.  Working on resolving this now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea why MS Access would get a failure for `union all` but not for `union`.  It should be producing the same data.  I also don't know why a memo field would be truncated in one case, but not the other.

However, the easiest way to solve your problem with `union all` is to do two inserts:

```
INSERT INTO outRawTbl
select * from [out|noRFI_BS_noRT];

insert into outRawTbl
select * from [out|noRFI_BS_RT];
```

Comment: The reason why `UNION` truncates Memo fields is that it performs a `DISTINCT` on the query, which means that it groups on all fields.  Memo fields cannot be grouped, so Access casts them to Text.

Comment: @sigil . . . I think most other databases would generate an error in this situation, rather than changing the type.  It does, however, give a hint as to the difference between the `union` and `union all` that explain your original problem.  In the meantime, doing two inserts can also solve the problem.